# Nginx: Nextcloud behind reverse proxy in subdir, php request fail

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

**My current Nginx webserver setup:**

1. Main server on port 80; (example.net)
2. Nextcloud server on port 82; (localhost:82) (Nextcloud version 14)

Both servers work perfectly if i call them directly.

What I want:
If a user calls "example.net/nextcloud" i want a proxy_pass to "localhost:82".

---

**What goes wrong:**
My current configuration works fine, except it fails to process the php script of the nextcloud instance if called trough the proxy.
Static files e.g. "example.net/nextcloud/robot.txt" works fine. And the proxy get the "localhost:82/robots.txt" file correctly.

My question is why it fails to process the php scripts correctly and how to fix it?

---

Current cfg:

1. Main server on Port 80

   ```
   server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;

       root /var/www/html;

       # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
       index index.html index.htm index.php

       server_name _;

       location / {
           # First attempt to serve request as file, then
           # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

       location /nextcloud {
           rewrite /nextcloud(/.*)$ $1 break;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
       }

       # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
       location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Nextcloud server, the offical nginx cfg example (only changed: port 82, php-fpm): https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/14/admin_manual/installation/nginx.html#nextcloud-in-the-webroot-of-nginx

   ```
   upstream php-handler {
       #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
       server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   }

   server {
       listen 82;
       server_name _;

       # Add headers to serve security related headers
       # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
       # topic first.
       # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;
       # includeSubDomains; preload;";
       #
       # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
       # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
       # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
       # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
       # could take several months.
       add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
       add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
       add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
       add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
       add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
       add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

       # Remove X-Powered-By, which is an information leak
       fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

       # Path to the root of your installation
       root /var/www/nextcloud/;

       location = /robots.txt {
           allow all;
           log_not_found off;
           access_log off;
       }

       # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
       # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
       #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
       #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json
       # last;

       location = /.well-known/carddav {
         return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
       }
       location = /.well-known/caldav {
         return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
       }

       # set max upload size
       client_max_body_size 512M;
       fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

       # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
       gzip on;
       gzip_vary on;
       gzip_comp_level 4;
       gzip_min_length 256;
       gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
       gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

       # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
       # This module is currently not supported.
       #pagespeed off;

       location / {
           rewrite ^ /index.php$request_uri;
       }

       location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
           deny all;
       }
       location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
           deny all;
       }

       location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+)\.php(?:$|/) {
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
           #Avoid sending the security headers twice
           fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
           fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
           fastcgi_pass php-handler;
           fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
           fastcgi_request_buffering off;
       }

       location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
           try_files $uri/ =404;
           index index.php;
       }

       # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
       # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
       location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff|svg|gif)$ {
           try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
           add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
           # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to
           # have those duplicated to the ones above)
           # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into
           # this topic first.
           # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
           #
           # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
           # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
           # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
           # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
           # could take several months.
           add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
           add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
           add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
           add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
           add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
           add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

           # Optional: Don't log access to assets
           access_log off;
       }

       location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
           try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
           # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
           access_log off;
       }
   }
   ```